# Extract a string combination from xml field using xslt to write in a later node

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

i'm hoping someone can assist, most likely with terminology / direction.
Completely new to xslt's. We have a stack of files which have some quirks (not very nice xml). I have managed to figure out attributes, matching and manipulating nodes.
We have one item I'm not sure how to proceed with.
A single node contains a comma delimited string. where there is an entry (or one or more) (a string)
e.g.

```
 <what_transactions_are_included_overall>,,,datanormalnational,dataspecialnational,,,,,,,</what_transactions_are_included_overall>
```

below are a set of nodes (not childs, same level)

```
<file>
 <planinfo>
   <plan_id>1</plan_id>
   <name>provider100_plan1</name>
   <what_transactions_are_included_overall>,,,datanormalnational,dataspecialnational,,,,,,,< /what_transactions_are_included_overall>
 </planinfo>

 <dataemailnational>
   <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
   <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
   <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
 </dataemailnational>
 <datanormalnational>
   <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
   <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
   <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
 </datanormalnational>
 <dataspecialnational>
   <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
   <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
   <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
 </dataspecialnational>
</file>
```

I have matched the children to normalise them and used attributes so i have this

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:param name="pTransTypeDataEmail"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="info">
     <info>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <plan_id>plan.id</plan_id>
    </info>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data_email_national"> <transaction_type transaction_type="0"> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> </transaction_type> </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="data_normal_national"> <transaction_type transaction_type="1"> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> </transaction_type> </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="data_special_national"> <transaction_type transaction_type="2"> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> </transaction_type> </xsl:template>
```

which gives me

```
 <transactiontype transaction_type="0">
   <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
   <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
   <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
 </transactiontype>
 <transactiontype transaction_type="1">
   <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
   <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
   <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
 </transactiontype>
 <transactiontype transaction_type="2">
   <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
   <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
   <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
 </transactiontype>
```

i'm really stuck on the direction to try and achieve this:

```
     <transactiontype type="0">
   <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
   <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
   <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
   <transactions_included_overall>false</transactions_included_overall>   <!-- e.g. it was NOT in the csv list  -->
 </transactiontype>
<transactiontype type="1">
   <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
   <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
   <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
   <transactions_included_overall>true</transactions_included_overall>   <!-- e.g. it was in the csv list -->
 </transactiontype>
 <transactiontype type="2">
   <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
   <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
   <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
   <transactions_included_overall>true</transactions_included_overall>  <!-- e.g. it was in the csv list -->
 </transactiontype>
```

i'm presuming its a combo of matching a pattern at the top not sure how to then co-ordinate that with the relevant match below it? should i start by creating an array (i can use 2.0) from the string or just use a sequence then use the index?... i feel close but not 100% sure.

appreciate any guidance, thanks

UPDATE
so after more searching I'm sure I'm getting there, downloaded a 2.0 processor (seems mac's xslt is only 1.0). Got some tokenise working e.g.

```
 <xsl:template match="planfile/plan/planinfo/what_transactions_are_included_overall">
    <xsl:variable name="Tokens" select="tokenize(current(),',')"/>
     </xsl:template>
```

then put a

```
    <xsl:value-of select="$Tokens[1]"/>
```

in the right place.

but now I'm hit with the problem that this in a diferrent scope. Realise also that variables aren't really variables and struggling to remember my functional programming class from 15 years ago!
 I'm sure I'm thinking procedurally to get this to work, but SO close I'm sure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make that a global variable by putting it outside any template:

```
<xsl:variable name="Tokens" select="tokenize(
     /file/planinfo/what_transactions_are_included_overall,',')"/>
```

then I would define another pair of templates with a mode

```
<!-- for elements whose name is in the include list -->
<xsl:template mode="transactionIncluded"
              match="*[local-name() = $Tokens]">
  <transactions_included_overall>true</transactions_included_overall>
</xsl:template>

<!-- for elements whose name is *not* in the include list -->
<xsl:template mode="transactionIncluded"
              match="*">
  <transactions_included_overall>false</transactions_included_overall>
</xsl:template>
```

and then you can use these templates at the appropriate place

```
<xsl:template match="data_email_national">
  <transaction_type transaction_type="0">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="transactionIncluded" />
  </transaction_type>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Edit**

From your comment:

> I've found, more than one `<plan></plan>` within the file, which has a single `<planinfo>` per `<plan>`. [...] i'm thinking some kind of local scope?

So you have something like

```
<file>
  <plan>
    <planinfo>
      <plan_id>1</plan_id>
      <name>provider100_plan1</name>
      <what_transactions_are_included_overall>,,,datanormalnational,,,,,,,,</what_transactions_are_included_overall>
    </planinfo>

    <datanormalnational>
      <cost_included>-1</cost_included>
      <qty_included>-1</qty_included>
      <cost_per_transaction>0</cost_per_transaction>
    </datanormalnational>
  </plan>
  <plan>
    <planinfo>
      <plan_id>1</plan_id>
      <name>provider100_plan1</name>
      <what_transactions_are_included_overall>,,,,dataspecialnational,,,,,,,</what_transactions_are_included_overall>
    </planinfo>
    <dataspecialnational>....</dataspecialnational>
  </plan>
</file>
```

and you want a different set of `what_transactions_are_included_overall` for each `plan`?  I think you can attack this using the [*tunnel parameter*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#tunnel-params) mechanism.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:param name="pTransTypeDataEmail"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="info">
     <info>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <plan_id>plan.id</plan_id>
    </info>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="plan">
   <!-- delegate to the normal identity template, but populate the tunnel
        parameter required by the transactionIncluded template -->
   <xsl:next-match>
     <xsl:with-param name="Tokens" tunnel="yes" select="tokenize(
       planinfo/what_transactions_are_included_overall,',')" />
   </xsl:next-match>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="transactionIncluded"
              match="*">
   <!-- use the Tokens parameter tunnelled in from the current <plan> -->
   <xsl:param name="Tokens" tunnel="yes" />
   <transactions_included_overall>
     <xsl:value-of select="if (local-name() = $Tokens) then 'true' else 'false'" />
   </transactions_included_overall>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="data_email_national">
   <transaction_type transaction_type="0">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="transactionIncluded" />
   </transaction_type>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- and similarly for the other transaction types -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A tunnel parameter is automatically passed down the chain of `apply-template` calls without the need for an explicit `xsl:param`/`xsl:with-param` at every level.

Comment: This is great , thanks Ian. Just been reading up on modes. Yet another thing to learn ;-)

Comment: @Ben one thing worth noting in this answer is that you can only use variable references in template `match` expressions if you're in XSLT 2.0, it's not allowed in 1.0 so there you'd have to do the test with an `<xsl:choose>` instead of different match rules.

Comment: thanks ian, yep i'd realised that early on. i'd rather let the code to the hard work than coding a complex 1.0 function (even though it means a java lib rather than using mac os x built in)

Comment: Hi Ian. I've found, more than one <plan></plan> within the file, which has a single <planinfo> per <plan>. (noting each <plan> has a <dataemailnational>, <mmsnational> etc. which are translated to <transaction_type transaction_type="n">. i've attempted different patterns in the tokenization (thinking that the first full xpath only matches wrong) but I know this isn't the case. could you offer any further insights? if i remove the <what_transactions_are_included_overall> from the 2nd <plan/planinfo> node, it works, but is then applied globally. i'm thinking some kind of local scope?

Comment: @Ben I think "tunnel parameters" are the concept you're looking for.  See my edit for details.

Comment: perfect, works a treat. its strange I have no idea how i could have possibly found that out without knowing the term! much appreciated